# OpenCV not detecting unknown faces

Tags: python, opencv

I recently made a project with opencv, that marks the attendance of a person with facial recognition, but it is not able to detect if a face is unknown or known. It just gives a name for every face. Can anyone help me?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# reading every frame
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    # resizing the image to 0.25 of original
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # find location of all the faces from our webcam feed [0] is not there so that
    # even if there are more than one faces in the feed
    facesCurrFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    # find encodings of the resized image sending in the small images and The location of
    # all the faces in current frame
    encodesCurrFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurrFrame)
    # one by one it grabs faces from facesCurrFrame list and Encodings From encodesCurrFrame list
    for enc, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurrFrame, facesCurrFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, enc)
        # this will return a list which will contain the distance or dis-similarities the image from camera
        # have and the images provided in the training data
        # the lowest value will have our match
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, enc)
        # print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
           #print(name)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            markAttendance(name)
```

Above code that captures the webcam footage and extracts the faces and performs the recognition.

I tried the program with some unknown faces but it is still giving me some name for that person.

Comment: You might want to adjust the threshold for the `face_recognition.compare_faces` function. From the doc : `tolerance – How much distance between faces to consider it a match. Lower is more strict. 0.6 is typical best performance.`

Comment: @AchilleG oh I just saw the documentations thanks for pointing that out.